# Send custom transaction id to paypal express checkout NVP

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I am using Paypal Express Checkout NVP API version 115

- I Already having my own shopping cart
- Shopping cart is already integrated to other 3rd party clearing house ( for credit card)
- I am using my own transaction id.

So, I am making 3 API Calls

- Set-EC (EC refer to Express checkout)
- Get-EC
- Do-EC

In SET-EC, I want to send my own transaction id which can be retrieved by the DO-EC,
They have listed `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TRANSACTIONID` in `Set-EC`.

So, I am sending my own transaction id in `PAYMENTREQUEST_n_TRANSACTIONID` in `SET-EC`
But, I am not able to receive it in `DO-EC` `PAYMENTINFO_n_TRANSACTIONID`.
Its showing me the 17 charac transaction id of Paypal.

Can anyone help me out to send my own custom transaction id and receive it upon payment completed.